# Prove the system of ODE is asymptotically stable using Lyapunov function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

Given the system of ODE
$$x_1'=x_2$$
$$x_2'=-a \sin x_1- b x_2$$
Where $a,b >0$ real numbers.
Using the Lyapunov function $$v(x_1,x_2)=\int_0^{x_1} a \sin{s}\,ds+\frac{1}{2} X^TPX$$
where $X=(x_1,x_2)$ and P some matrix, prove the system is asymptotically stable.

I need to find an appropriate matrix $P$ so that $v$ satisfies $v(0,0)=0$, $v(x_1,x_2)>0$ and $\frac{dv(0,0)}{dt}=0$, $\frac{dv}{dt}<0$,

I tried many values for $P$ but couldn't couldn't come up with anything.
Can you help me prove this?

Comment: So, if you just put in $p_{11}, p_{12}$ and so on as "values", what do you get (your ODEs depend on parameters, thus your Lyapunov function will most likely, too)?

Comment: What do you mean $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$? I don't think you need this.

Comment: I get $$ \int_0^{x_1} a \sin sds +1/2(p_{11}x_1^2+p_{22}x_2^2 +p_{12}x_1 x_2 +p_{21} x_1 x_2)$$ but it isn't positive defined, is it ?

Comment: $\frac{dV(0,0)}{dt}=0$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ v=Ax_1^2+2Bx_1x_2+Cx_2^2+a\int_0^{x_1}\sin sds. $$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dv}{dt}&=&2Ax_1x_1'+2B(x_1'x_2+x_1x_2')+2Cx_2x_2'+a\sin x_1\cdot x_1'\\
&=&2Ax_1x_2+2B(x_2^2-ax_1\sin x_1-bx_1x_2)+2C(-ax_2\sin x_1-bx_2^2)+ax_2\sin x_1\\
&=&2(A-bB)x_1x_2+a(1-2C)x_2\sin x_1-2bBx_1\sin x_1+2(B-bC)x_2^2.
\end{eqnarray}
Let
$$ A-2bB=0, 1-2C=0$$
which implies $A=2bB,C=\frac12$. The positive definiteness of $Ax_1^2+2Bx_1x_2+Cx_2^2$ requires
$$ B^2-AC<0 $$
or $$B^2-bB<0 \text{ or }B<b.$$
Choose $B=\frac14b, A=\frac12b^2$ and then
$$ \frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac12b^2x_1\sin x_1-\frac14bx_2^2\le0. $$